# UIPanGestureRecognizer Collision

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer

I have 6 UIImageViews each connected to  UIPanGestureRecognizer and they are all connected to the same method. The method is:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

I am following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on using GestureRecognizers. So, I was wondering how to detect collisions so that when one image collides with another image, some code is run. The code is different for each image.

Thanks

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: @SAPDEV Yes, I used the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want move the image with the recognizer maybe you should attach the recognizer to your view.

Belonging to this, the fastest way to do this, is (in the method that change the frame at your UIImageView)

```
for (UIImageView *iv in _imageArray){
   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(iv.frame, _selectedImageView.frame)) {
      NSLog(@"Collision");
   }
}
```

`_selectedImageView` is the image that your are moving and `_imageArray` is an array that contains all your UIImageView (in your case are 6).